# SSIS 2012, validation on package is invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

all. I have simple load table to table pack, and I included Execute_SQL_Task before Data_Flow_Task, with this code like below, and when I tried to run pack it says that it's package validation error,  as destination table is not exists yet . It will be created in very first step. Looks like this validation doesn't care about this, how I can go thru this?

`IF object_id('dbo.SALES', 'U') IS NULL
  CREATE table dbo.SALES ......`

`TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.SALES`

I also played with BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT and it didn't help.
Thanks all
M

Comment: I just ran my test code on other machine and it works fine (with or without dest table), not sure what setting it is to change in ssis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    If (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = ?) = 1
        CREATE TABLE dbo.Sales
    ELSE
        TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Sales
```